# Jmeter Regular expression extractor in not retuning any value

Tags: regex, jmeter

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="OPLResponse" 
VALUE="PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zOnNhbWxwPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6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"/>
```

i am trying to fetch value using following jmeter Regular expression
extractor

but it is not retuning any value.Can anyone help what exactly am i doing wrong in this regex.

> <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="OPLResponse" VALUE="(.+?)"/>

Comment: <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="OPLResponse" VALUE="(.+?)"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

> NAME="OPLResponse"  VALUE="([^"]+?)"

But I would advise you to use in JMeter the [CSS/Jquery Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) with just:

[image: CSS/JQuery Extractor]

Comment: Hi. The use of CSS selector extractor is a brilliant alternative. However, I'm skeptical about the regex used. Since there is a new line between "OPLResponse" and VALUE, the regex provided might not work. Would it be better, in this case, to just use VALUE as the left boundary rather than include NAME tag and its value along with it?